# VBscript throwing an exception saying thet `IsError` is undefined variable

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

It the following error handler is not working,Still throwing an exception that "IsError"Variable is not defined.

```
  If not IsError(objExcel1.Application.Match(ParentID, ob3.Columns(1), 0)) Then    
    ParentMatchRowNum = objExcel1.Application.Match(ParentID, ob3.Columns(1), 0)
  Else
     '-- do something
  End if
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Could you please help me here,how to fix that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell IsError isn't a VBscript function. Supporting evidence: [VBScript Functions](http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/vbscript_functions.php) and [Using VBScript Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227640%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). You'll note `IsError` is missing.

Instead you'll need to do error trapping. Something like this should suit.

```
On Error Resume Next
ParentMatchRowNum = objExcel1.Application.Match(ParentID, ob3.Columns(1), 0)
If err then
   err.clear
   'Do something
end if
on Error Goto 0
```

Comment: `on Error Goto 0` what it would do?

Comment: `On Error Goto 0` counters the `On Error Resume Next` and puts your script back at default behavior. I.E. Error messages for any run-time error.

Comment: Shall I need to place the code on every possible exception area or i can define its globally for all danger region?